# Replace method and for loops

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to do reverse transcription of a DNA sequence by reversing a string then find its corresponding pair ( if an 'A' appears then switch with a 'T') and return a new string that is 'reverse transcribed'. The loop seems to work only partially and not go through to the elif statements. I've tried two ways and have the same problem:

```
def structures(seq):
revlist = seq[::-1]
for item in revlist:
    if item == 'A':
        return revlist.replace('A','T',1000)
    elif item == 'T':
        return revlist.replace('T','A',1000)
    elif item == 'G':
        return revlist.replace('G','C',1000)
    elif item == 'C':
        return revlist.replace('C','G',1000)
    else:
        pass

structures('ATTTGCCCTA')

    # below is the second way I'm trying to code it

def structures(seq):
revlist = seq[::-1]
old = ['A','T','G','C']
new = ['T','A','C','G']
for item in revlist:
    if item == 'A':
        return revlist.replace(old[0],new[0])
    elif item == 'T':
        return revlist.replace(old[1],new[1])
    elif item == 'G':
        return revlist.replace(old[2],new[2])
    elif item == 'C':
        return revlist.replace(old[3],new[3])
    else:
        pass    

structures('ATTTGCCCTA')
```

Comment: "The loop seems to work only partially and not go through to the elif statements"  What do you expect `return` to do?/What do you think it is doing?

Comment: I expected return to return a new letter if the condition is met but it seems to quit after the first if statement. I'm not sure how to modify the code to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The method `str.replace` is meant to replace a *single substring* by another substring. Keep in mind that having multiple `str.replace` calls is inefficient since it means traversing your string many times while one would suffice.

To translate characters, you should use `str.translate`.

```
def dna_complement(dna):
    translation = str.maketrans({'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C'})
    return dna.translate(translation)[::-1]

print(dna_complement('AGTC'))
```

### Output

```
GACT
```

Comment: Appreciate the help Olivier !

Comment: Glad I could help. If that answer was helpful you can mark it as accepted so future users can find it.

Answer (score -1):

```
def structures(dna):
    revlist = ''
   for item in dna:
    if item == 'A':
        revlist = 'T' + revlist
    elif item == 'C':
        revlist = 'G' + revlist
    elif item == 'G':
        revlist = 'C' + revlist
    elif item == 'T':
        revlist = 'A' + revlist
return revlist
```

This code seems to work good. Instead of reversing the list, I researched another way of adding the information in reverse order which equates to the same thing. Credit to github

Comment: This is very inefficient duse to string being immutable, this means you create a new string on every iteration. Since in this particular case, dna can be very long, efficiency is important. You could improve the solution by making revlist a list and joining it at the end.